# Есть ли в TypeScript какие-либо для работы с переменными/свойствами, тип которых может отличаться от ожидаемого при запуске откомпилированного кода?

Tags: typescript

Насколько я знаю, TypeScript проверяет типы только на этапе компиляции в JavaScript, при этом в откомпилированный JS никаких проверок на тип не добавляется. Тем не менее, мне трудно поверить, что хвалёный TypeScript не даёт никаких средств, позволяющих упростить код, приведённый ниже...

В приведённом ниже классе мы парсим YAML-файл и получаем в результате объект `parsedConfigObject`. Мы знаем, какой тип ДОЛЖНО иметь каждое свойство этого объекта, однако не знаем и не можем знать, какое значение и какого типа будет при реальном запуске скрипта.

В методе `validateModeNumber` мы последовательно проверяем:

1. Существование `parsedConfigObject.modeNumber`
2. Тип `parsedConfigObject.modeNumber` (должно быть числом)
3. Является ли `parsedConfigObject.modeNumber` целым числом (нам нужно чтобы являлось)
4. Диапазон значений `parsedConfigObject.modeNumber` (допустим, позволены только значения 1 и 2.)

   ```
   class ConfigManager {

   private parsedConfigObject = null; // тут неверно имеет смысл указать интерфейс в качестве типа...

   constructor() {
     this.parsedConfigObject = yaml.load(PATH_TO_CONFIG_FILE);
     this.validateModeNumber();
   }


   private validateModeNumber(): void {

       const modeNumber = this.parsedConfigObject.modeNumber; 

       if (modeNumber === undefined) {
           throw new Error('Свойство "modeNumber" не найдено.');
       }

       if (typeof(modeNumber) != 'number') {
           throw new Error(`Свойство "modeNumber" должно быть числом, в реальности является: ${typeof this.parsedConfigObject.modeNumber}.`);
       }

       if (!isInteger(modeNumber)) {
           throw new Error(`Свойство "modeNumber" должно быть целым числом; реальное значение: ${this.parsedConfigObject.modeNumber}.`);           
       }

       if (modeNumber !== 1 && modeNumber !== 2) {
           throw new Error(`Свойство "modeNumber" должно быть в диапазоне от 1 до 2.`);
       }
   }
   }
   ```

За исключением второй строки, приведённый код является чистым JavaScript-ом (стандарта ES6). Даёт ли нам TypeScript какие-либо возможности для упрощения приведённого выше кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript проверяет типы только на этапе компиляции.

Этого вполне хватает, пока объекты не начинают приходить извне, например из конфигураций или в результате запросов.

Так как источник не может быть проверен, а возвращаемое значение в большинстве случаев указывается как `any` - кроме ручной проверки никак нельзя гарантировать, что то, что придет на самом деле будет нужного типа.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Печально, что TypeScript не сохраняет проверку типов при компиляции в JavaScript... Есть ли такая особенность в других языках, таких как Dart?

Comment: @БоковГлеб, что имеется ввиду под особенностью? автоматическое добавление проверок в компилированный код?

Comment: да. Добавление функций, проверяющих типы, в откомпилированный код, и вызов их в нужных местах.

Comment: @БоковГлеб, вы не используете тайпскрипт в полной мере, там есть куча флагов компилятора, которые будут заставлять вас указывать типы и тд.

Comment: @overthesanity, да я только за, чтобы использовать typescript в полной мере, только как это решит приведённую выше задачу...

Comment: @БоковГлеб, в `strict` моде не получится просто так присвоить `null` какому-то свойству, а потом обратиться к свойству `modeNumber`

Comment: @overthesanity нужно будет предварительно создать интерфейс?

Comment: @БоковГлеб, конечно

Comment: @overthesanity, скажите, а свойство `strict` совместимо с `Allow Java Script`? (Это сочетание нужно для использования сторонних JavaScript-библиотек).

Comment: @БоковГлеб, `allowJs` не имеет отношения к `strict`, `strict` - это синтаксический сахар поверх 6 опций (смотреть доку)